# Filter companies that have at least 3 specific products

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerbi, etl, powerquery

I have an excel pivot table (and a table dataset behind) that has the structure like the one below. How can I filter/show only companies (Col A) with Products (Col B) 1 AND 2 AND 3? Sounds like something easy but can't find a way to do that. No problem by achieving this using Power Query (available in Power BI or Excel).

```
A1: Company 1 | B1: Product 1
A2: Company 1 | B2: Product 2
A3: Company 1 | B3: Product 3
A4: Company 1 | B4: Product 4
A5: Company 2 | B5: Product 1
A6: Company 3 | B6: Product 1
A7: Company 4 | B7: Product 1
A8: Company 4 | B8: Product 2
A9: Company 4 | B9: Product 3
A10: Company 4 | B9: Product 4
A11: Company 4 | B9: Product 5
```

Comment: So you'd only want to display/include Companies 1 and 4?

Comment: Yes! filtering that way would show only companies 1 and 4

Comment: We have a power query way to achieve that and it's working. do you know any way to do the same with pure excel? just curious because sounds like something very easy.

Comment: See my answer...you can use a helper column that uses `COUNTIFS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using Power Query.

Starting with this brought into Power Query from the table in Excel:

[image]

I then group on Company (Transform > Group By):

[image]

[image]

Then I add a new custom column (Add Column > Custom Column) to flag whether each company has the 3 products included in its associated grouped table's Product column:

[image]

[image]

Then I filter out the FALSE entries from the new custom column (use button at top right of Custom column):

[image]

Then I expand the Products column from the embedded table in the AllData column (use button at top right of AllData column).

[image]

[image]

Then I remove the Custom column:

[image]

Here's the M code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Company", type text}, {"Product", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Company"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each List.ContainsAll([AllData][Product], {"Product 1","Product 2","Product 3"})),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = true)),
#"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "AllData", {"Product"}, {"Product"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded AllData",{"Custom"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: you are a genious. this worked like a charm!!! Thank you. Do you know if that is possible to achieve without power query? with normal excel filtering techniques and capabilities?

Comment: I *believe* all you really need to do, working from your initial table in Excel, is extract the product number to a new column in the table: e.g., `=NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT([@Product],1))`; then use `=COUNTIFS([Company],[@Company],[Column1],">=1",[Column1],"<=3")` in another new column; then filter that last new column to show all 3s.

Comment: yes, but in real life the product names have no numbers. thanks

Comment: I like @Zack's way of flagging the products so you can use the names in his Excel only approach.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'll need to do a couple of things to do this entirely in Excel:

1. Add a new table that lists the products, with a column indicating whether that product is included/flagged:

[image]

2. Update your company/product table to have **2** helper columns: One to `VLOOKUP` whether the product is flagged, and one to indicate whether a company has all 3 flagged products:

   - The first helper column would use a formula like `=VLOOKUP([@Product],tProducts,2,FALSE)`.
   - The second helper column would use a formula like `=COUNTIFS([Company],[@Company],[Product Flagged],TRUE)>=3`.

[image]

Rows with a `TRUE` in Column D have 1 each of Products 1, 2, and 3 (unless you have rows with duplicate company/product combinations, where it gets a bit trickier):

In your pivot table, you can filter by this helper column:

[image]

Comment: would that work with product names instead of integers?

Comment: Updating my answer to work with product names. The basic solution would be the same, but you'd have to add another table to indicate "flagged" products.

Comment: can you explain why it and when exactly it would get trickier (what you wrote in your answer) thanks so much.

Comment: If you have a company with the same product listed twice, it would affect the results of the `COUNTIF` function. So if `Company A` had `Product 1` listed twice, and `Product 2` listed once, it would show as having all products, even without having `Product 3`.